# Regex to automatically match and output product names

Tags: regex, logging

We have log files which capture product names shown in bold (i.e. the custom0== value):

> category_l1==536&+category_l2==638&+category_l3==730&+category_l4==765&+custom0==**product
>   a**
>
> category_l1==536&+category_l2==638&+category_l3==2626&+category_l4==667&+brand==def&+custom0==**product
>   b**&+id==productid_au_1111111111_29208371462211
>
> category_l1==536&+category_l2==638&+category_l3==2626&+category_l4==667&+brand==def&+custom0==**product
>   b**&+id==productid_au_2222222222_29208371462211
>
> category_l1==536&+category_l2==638&+category_l3==2626&+category_l4==667&+brand==def&+custom0==*Product
>   c**&+id==productid_au_3333333333_29208371462211

To group results by product we've created new **Product Name** field and used regex code to output product names. We've use this regex code, so if there's a match for **Product A** then **Product A 123** is the outputed:

```
CASE

  WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH(Keyword, '.*product a.*')) THEN "Product A 123"

  WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH(Keyword, '.*product b.*')) THEN "Product B 456"

  WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH(Keyword, '.*product c.*')) THEN "Product C 789"

ELSE 

  "Other"

END
```

**Problem** - we have to manually create multiple regex lines and manually type each custom0 value to output for each product name

**Question** - is there a single regex command we can use that scans the **custom0==** value and outputs as the product name for each product? So value that's after **custom0==** AND before **&+?**

Comment: Which database are you using; please add the appropriate database tag to the question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex pattern `.*custom0==(?P<product_name>.*)&+` ?